# Running 'grep' command using exec functions

Tags: c++, operating-system, exec, system-calls, execvp

I am trying to run grep command using execvp. I have to save the output into an output file like output.txt. The code, I have tried is given below:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    pid_t pid = fork();
    int status = 0;
    char* args[] = {"grep", "-n", "out", "*", ">", "output.txt", NULL};
    //char* args[] = {"out", "/os_lab/assign_01/*", "/usr", NULL};
    if(pid == 0){
        cout<<"I am Child Process\n";
        status = 2;
        execvp("grep", args);
    }
    else if(pid > 0){
        cout<<"I am Parent Process\n";
        wait(&status);
    }   
    else{
        cout<<"Error in system call\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code, the output on the terminal is as follows:

```
I am Parent Process
I am Child Process
grep: *: No such file or directory
grep: >: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Redirection and wildcard expansion are handled by your shell (if it supports them), not the program itself. You need to expand `*` (see `man 3 glob`), open the output file, and set standard output to be that file before you `exec` (and pass the result of the wildcard expansion as arguments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `execvp()` function calls directly the program and execute it with the provided arguments. The  use of `wildcards` like `*` are provided by the shell terminal, so the `grep` is understanding the `*` as a file to be `grep'ed`.

If you want to call the grap using wildcards and the operator `>` you should use the function `system()` on C++.

The following code should work:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    pid_t pid = fork();
    int status = 0;
    //char* args[] = {"grep", "-n", "out", "*", ">", "output.txt", NULL};

    
    //char* args[] = {"out", "/os_lab/assign_01/*", "/usr", NULL};
    if(pid == 0){
        cout<<"I am Child Process\n";
        status = 2;
        //execvp("grep", args);
        system("grep -n out * > output.txt");
    }
    else if(pid > 0){
        cout<<"I am Parent Process\n";
        wait(&status);
    }   
    else{
        cout<<"Error in system call\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Btw, when I tried to run 'ls -l' using the same the code, it worked. That's why, I tried this for grep as well. Kindly elaborate this..

Comment: Also, how can we run grep using exec functions??

Comment: The `ls -l` works because the functions and it parameters does not depends on the `shell` to me executed. (no wildcards and pipes), for using `grep` with `exec` functions you should use it in the format `exec -n "value-looking" file.txt` -> `char* argument_list[] = {"grep", "-n","value-looking","file.txt", NULL};  execvp("ls", argument_list);`

Comment: What should I do, if I want to match the string with all the files in the current directory and save the results in a file named output.txt. If I am on terminal, I use ```grep -n "value-looking" * > output.txt``` and this will save the results in a file output.txt.

Comment: use the code provided in the answer, calling the `system()`function

Comment: Note that `fork`ing the process is essentially redundant if you're using `system`, right?

Comment: yes, u r right. The fork system call creates a new process. The new process created by fork() is a copy of the current process except for the returned value. The exec() system call replaces the current process with a new program.nice detail on this article [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fork-system-call/)